# Does the distributive law for dot products go for both addition and subtraction?

Tags: vectors

I know that $\vec a\cdot(\vec b+\vec c)=\vec a\cdot\vec b+\vec a\cdot\vec c$, but is it also true that $\vec a\cdot(\vec b-\vec c)=\vec a\cdot\vec b-\vec a\cdot\vec c$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $c' = -c$. Then $b-c = b+c'$ Then $a\cdot (b-c) = a\cdot (b+c') = a\cdot b + a\cdot c' = a\cdot b -a\cdot c$.

So, yes.

Answer (score 2):

$ \vec b - \vec c = \vec b + (- \vec c) \ \forall \vec c \in \mathbb{R^n}$